# Copy the content/file to all subdirectory in a directory using terminal

Tags: command-line, cp

I want to copy a file to all subfolders in a folder. How can I do this with the command line?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How to put a file in the current working directory in all subfolders (and maybe their subfolders, depending on what you want to do)

This will put the file in all of the subfolders, but not their subfolders:

```
for d in */; do cp water.txt "$d"; done
```

---

This will put the file `water.txt` (change all instances of water.txt to the filename you want to copy) in all the subfolders and their subfolders

```
for i in ./* # iterate over all files in current dir
do
    if [ -d "$i" ] # if it's a directory
    then
        cp water.txt "$i" # copy water.txt into it
    fi
done
```

Info from [this linuxquestions thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-copy-a-file-to-all-subfolders-in-a-directory-using-a-single-command-820478/)

Comment: Hey, what if I only want to put water.txt in the end subfolder of tar_dir?

Answer (score 20):

You could use that one-liner:

`find <target-dir> -type d -exec cp <the file> {} \;`

limit depth to 1 -> only the immediate directories

`find <target-dir> -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec cp <the file> {} \;`

Comment: This does all subdirectories recursively, not just the immediate subdirectories

Comment: @Anake updated my answer

Comment: This answer is excellent!

Comment: I had to reverse flags  `-maxdepth 1 -type d` on RHEL